# Export GPG Private Key WITHOUT knowning the passphrase

Tags: gpg-agent, pgp, openpgp

so I spent many hours on this now and I hope someone can give me any useful input.
I want to export an encrypted secret key from GPG (which lies in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d`) but I do not have the passphrase. So the normal `gpg --armor --export-secret-keys <name>` does not work for me. My goal is to get that encrypted private key into the armored OpenPGP format (while still being encrypted).

Just a change of format without any decryption happening.

So I dove into the RFC 4880 standard to understand how the packet structure works but that doesn't lead me anywhere.

I hope this is understable.

Is it even possible to do this manually or is the key decrypted and reencrypted a different way during gpg's export function?

Comment: Yes, in a GnuPG that uses private-keys-v1.d (definitely 2.2 up, I think but can't confirm 2.1) the keys are encrypted _and formatted_ differently than RFC4880 (OpenPGP), thus for export must be decrypted (unless already cached in the agent), re-formatted, and re-encrypted. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/230450/generating-multiple-gpg-private-keys-for-provenance .

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, fuuuck.. I am sitting at a CTF right now and really thought It was possible lol. Thank you so much for confirming it is not!